# kafka AdminClient not working in deployed environment

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka to connect to kafka and to check the status of the kafka server, I am using `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient`. It is working fine in my local but but when I deploy into QA environment, it doesn't start, complaining not able to create AdminClient bean. My guess is that AdminClient would be using any specific port, which would not be open in QA environment.

Does someone know if this is the case and which port KafkaAdmin connect to? Spring kafka without KafkaAdmin seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special. The `KafkaAdmin` is based on some provided config:

```
/**
 * Create an instance with an {@link AdminClient} based on the supplied
 * configuration.
 * @param config the configuration for the {@link AdminClient}.
 */
public KafkaAdmin(Map<String, Object> config) {
```

This config is indeed use for the `AdminClient` internal instance:

```
 adminClient = AdminClient.create(this.config);
```

and that one is based on the `AdminClientConfig`:

```
/**
 * Create a new AdminClient with the given configuration.
 *
 * @param conf The configuration.
 * @return The new KafkaAdminClient.
 */
public static AdminClient create(Map<String, Object> conf) {
    return KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(new AdminClientConfig(conf), null);
}
```

So, all the properties required for `AdminClient` connection you can find in that `AdminClientConfig`. And pay attention that host/port by default is exactly the same as it is for any other clients:

```
public static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG = CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG;
```

and

```
private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_DOC = CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_DOC;
```

So, when you create a `KafkaAdmin` instance, you should provide at least that `bootstrap.servers` property.

Also would be great to see a stack trace which happens in that mentioned environment.

Comment: thanks for elaborating it @Artem I would be having some other problem as when I enabled adminClient again and deployed there was no error. So, there might be some other problem with Kafka connectivity in general temporarily.